# Chazan waiting for individual with yahrtzeit

Tags: tefilla, kaddish, maariv, yahrtzeit

If there are 10 individuals finished maariv shmone esrei, should/must the chazan wait for the mourner with a yahrtzeit to finish davening? (Assuming there is no particular rule for the shul) Is there an amount of time which the poskim mention regarding *tircha d'tzibura*, or should the tzibur continue the way they ordinarily do and if this individual wants to say kaddish then he should daven with a minyan more his speed?

(Obviously, to avoid conflicts CYLOR)

Comment: Why would they wait? If someone wants to say Kaddish, they can gather 10 people and say verses or Torah study and then Kaddish. This can be done at any time 24/7. I'm not sure what you think special is going on at this Minyan that they would be forced to delay.

Comment: *Tircha Detzibbur* in terms of a quantitative amount of time, I think, doesn't exist. (Perhaps, it should.) The chazzan and shul rabbi need to judge that. But, in general, it seems that you can sense when it's getting unreasonable to wait. DoubleAA's suggestion is not just feasible, but is somewhat common in many minyanim that I've seen.