# Saying kaddish vs. Davening slower

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, mourning-aveilus, kaddish, kavana-concentration

This is the flip side of [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84785/chazan-waiting-for-individual-with-yahrtzeit) question. Related to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/54055/how-does-one-say-kaddish-if-he-is-in-the-middle-of-amidah).

If someone has an obligation to say kaddish yatom (in this hypothetical, he is not davening for the amud and he is saying ma'ariv) should he speed up his own shmoneh esrei to be able to say kaddish or daven at his personal, slower speed 
which allows for better concentration, but miss the chance to say kaddish?

Is there a way to "weigh" the relative obligations or importance when choosing between the two? Does the ability to daven faster but the preference to slow down factor in?

If the answer is simply (as per the comments on the linked question) that saying kaddish at some point not tied to davening is what matters, a source for that would be useful. [I am not creating the hypothetical wrinkle that "he won't be able to get a minyan together at any other time.]

Comment: "saying kaddish at some point not tied to davening is what matters" If you're referring to my comments, that isn't what I meant to imply. Doing good things is what matters. If someone really wants to say Kaddish, they can do so whenever they want and sanctifying God's name in public is certainly a Good Thing. They can also study Torah, give charity, pray more seriously, perform acts of kindness, etc. Leading sundry prayer services (including saying Kaddish after public study) is 'just' a fairly ubiquitous Good Thing that needs a volunteer: might as well be someone seeking those opportunities

Comment: Remember until quite recently it was totally normal for a mourner to only say one or two kaddeshim every few days when opportunities would present themselves. Everyone saying every Kaddish has become common in the last ~200 years for sociological reasons, but it's not really a fundamental part of the Jewish mourning experience.

Comment: Where do you see that someone would have an obligation to say Kaddish Yosom?